# Qual o motivo desse Reference Error

Tags: javascript, design-pattern, proxy

O método `_validaFunção` está no mesmo contexto do método create, então porque o create retorna um `Uncaught ReferenceError: validaFuncao is not defined`?

```
class ProxyFactory
{
    static _validaFuncao(funcao)
    {

        return typeof (funcao) === typeof (Function);
    }

    static create(objeto, itensObservados, acao)
    {
        return new Proxy(objeto,
            {
                get(alvo, propriedade, receptor)
                {
                    if ((itensObservados.includes(propriedade)) && (_validaFuncao(alvo[propriedade])))
                    {
                        return function ()
                        {
                            Reflect.apply(alvo[propriedade], alvo, arguments);
                            return acao(alvo);
                        }
                    }
                    return Reflect.get(alvo, propriedade, receptor);
                },
                set(alvo, propriedade, valor, reciever)
                {
                    if (itensObservados.includes(propriedade))
                    {
                        acao(alvo);
                    }
                    return Reflect.set(alvo, propriedade, valor, reciever);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

O `if` dentro do create não encontra o _validaFuncao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você definiu o método como `static` e um método estático só é acessado **diretamente** na classe, veja:

```js
class Estatica{
    static metodo(a) {
        return a + 1;
    }
}

//funciona, pois estou invocando o método diretamente da classe
console.log(Estatica.metodo(1));

//Não funciona, pois estou invocando atraves de uma instância do objeto
var est = new Estatica();
console.log(est.metodo(1));
```

Com invocações dentro da classe ainda seria a mesma coisa, veja:

```js
class Estatica{
    static metodo(a) {
        return a + 1;
    }
    
    static chamadaDiretaClasse(valor){
        return Estatica.metodo(valor);
    }
    
    static chamadaDiretaClasseThis(valor){
        return this.metodo(valor);
    }
    
    static chamadaDireta(valor){
        return metodo(valor);
    }
}

//Funciona, pois dentro de chamadaDiretaClasse o método é invocado através da classe
console.log(Estatica.chamadaDiretaClasse(1));

//Ainda funciona, pois o this dentro desse escopo se referencia a classe, então ele equivale a Estativa
console.log(Estatica.chamadaDiretaClasseThis(2));

//Não funciona, pois o um método estático não pode ser invocado dessa forma
console.log(Estatica.chamadaDireta(3));
```

Então, para resolver o seu problema basta adicionar a classe a que pertence o método `_validaFuncao`, que em seu caso ficaria como `ProxiFactory._validaFuncao`.

[Veja mais sobre](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)